# Passing function instead of string for jquery easing using CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jquery-easing

I'm trying to pass my own function into a jquery animation to create my own easing function. This code is written in coffeescript and is actually called, but does not perform an easing function. It merely acts like a callback function. Has anyone else experienced this?

```
    easing : (x, t, b, c, d) -> 

        if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75))
            return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b

        else if (t < (2/2.75))
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b

        else if (t < (2.5/2.75))
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b

        else
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b

    show : () =>

        @container.slideDown @config.animationTime, @easing(), () =>

            @config.visible = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/#easing):

> As of jQuery 1.4.3, an optional string naming an easing function may be used.

So the `easing` argument should be a string which names the easing to use, not an easing function itself. Furthermore, this is a method call:

```
@easing()
```

while this is a reference to your easing function:

```
@easing
```

If you want to define a custom easing, you have to do it globally by adding a property to `$.easing`:

```
$.easing.whatever = (x, t, b, c, d) ->
    #...
```

and then you reference it by name:

```
@container.slideDown @config.animationTime, 'whatever', () => ...
```

Comment: hey worked perfectly. I should've known this, didn't do my homework before posting. Thanks for the solution

Comment: The easing stuff isn't exactly clearing documented, at least it isn't documented anywhere that I've been able to find.